# Failing to deploy a Course Builder on Google App Engine

Tags: bash, google-app-engine, terminal, embedded-linux

I am really not sure what I am doing. I have no idea what is coding , and I never used the terminal on my Mac. I am trying to set up a Course Builder on Google App Engine, and the instructions are telling to to follow these steps:

Deploy from Mac and Linux:

Open a command prompt and get to your coursebuilder directory. Type the following command:

```sh
bash ./scripts/deploy.sh <your_project_id>
```

If your deployment was successful, you can visit your new site.

That is what I am getting:

```sh
elena$ bash ./scripts/deploy.sh on-point-learning
bash: ./scripts/deploy.sh: No such file or directory
```

I am completely lost, is there anyone who can help me? And please in English, I speak no Computer, even using the Terminal makes my hands sweaty and my heartbeat unstable.

p.s.: I do apologize and maybe this questions was answered before but I understand nothing in the questions/answers I read.

Comment: It says that it cannot find the `deploy.sh` script. You probably missed a `cd` command in the instructions. You can try using `ls` to see what files there are. If you don't see `scripts`, you are in the wrong directory. If you can `ls scripts/` but don't see `deploy.sh` in the output, something was supposed to place that file there but didn't. You may need to download again, or double check the directory / folder you're supposed to be in. Either way, you don't provide enough details to really help you, so I'm voting to close this question. See [ask].

Comment: Thank you Robert, I was in the wrong directory. Thank you for navigating me into the correct place.

Comment: Now, I am missing some Xcodes - which I don't know what they mean. It seems like by the time I'll get to create my course, I will learn coding and things I didn't know exist.

Answer (score 0):

1. First, you need to have downloaded and installed the Google App Engine SDK. Follow all the steps documented by Google [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/downloads). You need to follow all the steps so that all the files are installed/copied and the necessary shortcuts created
2. Your course builder will be in a folder (directory)

   a) Open command line and change directory to your project folder i.e. something like `cd <path_to_project_folder>`

   b) Type `gcloud app deploy`

**Note:** Google's documentation says - *Use the install script to add Cloud SDK tools to your PATH*. You need to make sure you do that so that typing commands in your command line will work

3. If you do not want to tinker with your command line or you want to make things very very simple, then you can try using a GUI, for example our App, [NoCommandLine](https://nocommandline.com)

   a) Select File > Add Existing Application

   b) Navigate to your Course Builder Folder and select the file named `app.yaml`

   c) Select your programming language and the framework (if neccessary), click on `Add`.

   d) To run your project (on your local machine) or deploy it to Production, you just select it from the UI, and click the `run` or `deploy` icon.

Comment: I'll try doing it